# Wordpress Custom Post Type Category System

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I currently have a custom post type `Projects` that I need to have a categorization system. Basically, I need to have the page heirarchy as such: Projects -> Project Listing -> Main Project Page.

Does anyone know a preferred method of doing this? I currently have a page set up for all projects and that works fine. That pulls in all categories. The next step would be sorting project listings based on category. I need to set custom templates for these as well. Am I on the right track here, or is there a simpler approach that anyone can think of. Also, currently if make a page projects/project-listing it doesn't use my custom template I created. It seems to use the index.php template, which is not what I want. I need to have the url structure to be as listed. `projects/project-listing`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, After Wordpress 4.7 custom templates are also available to custom post types, when defining a template

// your code here
you can add this while making post type projects 
'supports'  => array( 'title', 'editor','page-attributes' )